# How to update chromium-browser to 57 on ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: google-chrome, 16.10, chromium

How can I upgrade/ update my current Chromium from 56 to 57 on Ubuntu 16.10 using the terminal?

I can get Chrome 57 from their official site - download the `.deb` file then install it but Chromium is still on version 56.

I attempt on my terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade chromium-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
chromium-browser is already the newest version (56.0.2924.76-0ubuntu0.16.10.1335).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 55 not to upgrade.
```

It seems that the latest version of Chromium for Ubuntu is 56.0.2924.76 only?

Comment: Try the PPA https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage. It looks like version 57 hasn't made it to the repositories yet.

Comment: And "chromium-browser 40 hours ago
Failed to build: amd64 armhf i386" on the right-hand side of the page under "Latest updates" from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage?field.series_filter=

Comment: @DKBose yes I had a problem upgrading it actually. Still on 5.6....

Comment: For reasons I don't know, building chromium-browser has been difficult to build on past occasions as well leading to the Chrome version available being more recent than the chromium version.

Comment: @DKBose I think it is easier just to download the `.deb` from chrome official website instead of upgrading/ installing chromium.

Comment: I've been using google-chrome for a long time and will continue to do so though I must point out that many people, here and elsewhere, avoid google-chrome on privacy grounds.